# Excel Columns into Java Using API

Tags: java, arrays, excel, apache-poi

I had to create a program that calculates the GPA, using apache poi that reads the xlsx excel file. It coints 220 rows and 4 columns, such as

```
Course Number    Course Name    Credit Hours Course Multipler
110              Eng 1 CP        5.0          1.0
```

There are 220 other courses.
However, I was able to print those data using cell.getStringCellValue and cell.getNumericCellValue, but I can't get these printed data into each array.

I wanted to create an array called courseNumList and put courseNumList[0] the first course Number, and the second course number in courseNumList[1].. on and on..

I want to create 4 arrays, but what is a good way?

```
            private static ArrayList<Object> c = new ArrayList <Object>();

            public static void readXLSXFile() throws IOException {

    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/14KimTa/Desktop/Downloads/Course_List.xlsx");

    XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

    XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row; 
    XSSFCell cell;

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext())
    {
        row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

        while (cells.hasNext())
        {
            cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();

            if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            {               
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                                    c.add(getStringCellValue());
            }

            else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
            }
        }           

    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

this is my code so far.

I tried to create each columns into arrays, but it is not working at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new class to define your data, `Course`, with one field for each of your columns (4 fields).  Then I would create some kind of `List` (`ArrayList<Course>` looks good) to hold all `Courses`.  An array of `Course`s would work too, since you know how many there are from the start.  In a loop, I would create one `Course` object for each row, setting the fields based on the values from `cell.getStringCellValue()` and `cell.getNumericCellValue()`, adding the `Course` to the `List` (or array) after processing each row.

Comment: Each row doesn't go into one array like I intend to, but all the data just simply goes into arrayList[0].. If i try arrayList[1], it would return an error

Comment: Please show your code that creates your objects and inserts them into your `ArrayList`.

Comment: private static ArrayList<Object> c = new ArrayList <Object>();

this instantiates the array list of c

and

c.add(cell.getStringCellValue()) adds it

Comment: Create your `ArrayList` before your first `while` loop.  Create a `Course` object inside the first `while` loop.  Don't have a second inner `while` loop, because you know what each of the 4 columns are.  Get each of the 4 expected cells, and set the attributes in your `Course` from each of the 4 values, then add the `Course` to your `ArrayList` at the bottom of the `while` loop.

Comment: I have trouble following your lines... could you show me an example please? I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating one array per each column is a good idea. Keeping track of data in the same row by following the same indexes in the 4 arrays may be cumbersome and bad practice.

I would rather create a Java class - `Course` - with 4 fields -`courseNumber`, `courseName`, `creditHours` and `courseMultiplier`. Then, I would create a collection of such objects, e.g. `Collection<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();`, and populate it according to the data read from Excel - one object per row.

EDIT:

I'd suggest you create a custom type instead of using `Object` for your `ArrayList` type parameter. You're not gaining much by using `Object`.

Then, for each row, you'd do the following:

```
//...obtain your values from cells and populate `courseNumber`, `courseName`,`creditHours` and `courseMultiplier` accordingly
Course course = new Course();
course.setCourseNumber(courseNumber);
course.setCourseName(courseName);
course.setCreditHours(creditHours);
course.setCourseMultiplier(courseMultiplier);
c.add(course);
```

This snippet of code should be placed inside the loop you use for iterating through rows.

Comment: I'm having trouble with putting one object per one row

Comment: How do I "obtain" the values? should I use add function?

Comment: e.g. `double courseNumber = row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();`

Comment: Forget about the inner `while` loop.

Comment: Try to use the POI API properly. Check the type of the cell beforehand. Or set the cell type accordingly.